# is map function is not working in next js 13.4.17 or above

Tags: next.js, typeerror, map-function

i am using next js 13.4.19. i have made a GET api and trying to access the data available at mongodb database. but when i try to map the data it shows me error
Error: data?.map is not a function.
This is my product Schema

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  price: Number,
  category: String,
});
export const Product =
  mongoose.models.products || mongoose.model("products", productSchema);
```

here is my GET API

```
import { dbStr } from "@/database/connection";
import { Product } from "@/model/product/product";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function GET() {
  let data = [];
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(dbStr);
    data = await Product.find();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }

  return NextResponse.json({ data }, { success: true });
}
```

i have tested the api its working fine and showing the data as follows

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "_id": "64fd823b07208cd28468b70e",
            "name": "samsung",
            "price": 1200,
            "category": "mobile",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "64fe1aa2e801f1d8af66b362",
            "name": "abc",
            "price": 2,
            "category": "abc",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "64fe1ae7e801f1d8af66b366",
            "name": "shehz",
            "price": 200,
            "category": "gg",
            "__v": 0
        },
    ]
}
```

but when i try to to get the data from above given api i got error

```
 import React from "react";
async function getData() {
  const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/products");
  // The return value is *not* serialized
  // You can return Date, Map, Set, etc.

  if (!res.ok) {
    // This will activate the closest `error.js` Error Boundary
    throw new Error("Failed to fetch data");
  }

  return res.json();
}
const GetProducts = async () => {
  const data = await getData();
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Get All Products Data</h1>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <td>name</td>
            <td>price</td>
            <td>category</td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {data?.map((item) => {
            return (
              <tr key={item._id}>
                <td>{item.name}</td>
                <td>{item.price}</td>
                <td>{item.category}</td>
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};

export default GetProducts;
```

at the server side i am facing the issue

```
error TypeError: data?.map is not a function
    at GetProducts (./src/component/GetProducts.js:69:41)
  26 |         </thead>
  27 |         <tbody>
> 28 |           {data?.map((item) => {
     |                 ^
  29 |             return (
  30 |               <tr key={item._id}>
  31 |                 <td>{item.name}</td>
```

Comment: try `return await res.json()`

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this? data has a key data inside it that you need to access to map over it.

```
const {data} = await getData();
```